# Issue with gradle job in jenkins with JDK 1.8

Tags: jenkins, gradle, java-8

I am able to run `gradlew test clean` in the command prompt where Jenkins is running. When I use Gradle Wrapper and run `clean test` in Jenkins, the job is failing with:

```
   Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
   > invalid source release: 1.8
```

My wrapper is using gradleVersion = 1.10 and the gradlew -v shows the following:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CDS-UnitTest\workspace>gradlew -v

  ------------------------------------------------------------
  Gradle 1.10
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
  Build number: none
  Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

  Groovy:       1.8.6
  Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
  Ivy:          2.2.0
  JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
  OS:           Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
```

I'm not able to figure out why it is failing in Jenkins for JDK 1.8 while it works in the command line.

Jenkins console:

```
 [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\CDS-UnitTest\workspace\gradlew.bat" -DSOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER=14 clean test && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
 ...

 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
 > invalid source release: 1.8
```

Comment: When you setup your gradle job in Jenkins you can choose between invoking gradle directly or using the wrapper. Are you sure that you choose to use the wrapper ?

Comment: Yes, I've chosen `Use Gradle Wrapper` option in Jenkins.

Comment: And what is the version of java visible from Jenkins? You can check it via Jenkins console.

Comment: I updated JDK in 'Manage Jenkins' and that fixed the issue. I thought the JDK used by Jenkins is independent of the JDK used by the job. It isn't. Thanks.